# Find out if an address/port is already bound under Android

Tags: android, wifi, port

My Android application needs to use an IP address/port to connect to a server.
How to know (by code) if the port is already bound or not?

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest way is to attempt the bind and check the error return (if it succeeded, then it wasn't previously bound).